# Getting parameters from ArrayList of structs

Tags: c#, arraylist, parameters, struct

I want to create an arraylist in which I'll store structs describing mp3 players, and I want to access said parameters inside a for loop so I can print these out in Console.

My problem is accessing the parameters inside the for loop, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Also this is homework, so the arraylist and struct are a necessity.

```
static public void mp3speler()
    {

        mp3 speler1 = new mp3(1, 1, "a", "b", "c");
        mp3 speler2 = new mp3(2, 1, "a", "b", "c");
        mp3 speler3 = new mp3(3, 1, "a", "b", "c");
        mp3 speler4 = new mp3(4, 1, "a", "b", "c");
        mp3 speler5 = new mp3(5, 1, "a", "b", "c");

        ArrayList mp3Array = new ArrayList();
        mp3Array.Add(speler1);
        mp3Array.Add(speler2);
        mp3Array.Add(speler3);
        mp3Array.Add(speler4);
        mp3Array.Add(speler5);


        for (int i = 0; i < mp3Array.Count; i++)
        {
            string placeHolder = "0"; //= ((mp3)mp3Array[0].ID);
            Console.WriteLine(@"MP3 Speler {0}
Make: {1}
Model: {2}
MBSize: {3}
Price: {4}", placeHolder, placeHolder, placeHolder, placeHolder, placeHolder);
        }
    }

    struct mp3
    {
        public int ID, MBSize;
        public string Make, Model, Price;

        public mp3(int ID, int MBSize, string Make, string Model, string Price)
        {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.MBSize = MBSize;
            this.Make = Make;
            this.Model = Model;
            this.Price = Price;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ArrayList` of struct? Don't do that. Use `List<YourStruct>` avoid boxing/unboxing.

Comment: `struct`? mutable `struct`?? Please make your life easier and change `struct mp3` to `class Mp3Player`... or at least read on "class vs. struct in C#" articles.

Comment: also never expose fields as `public`, you should be converting it to a property

Comment: Just for your knowledge - ArrayList is very inefficient when using value types (like structs). I understand it's a requirement, but keep it in mind.

Comment: Homework with ArrayList? Someone is teaching you wrong stuff. That's worse than not teaching anything...

Answer (score 4):

1. Use generic `List<T>` instead of `ArrayList`. It will prevent your structs from boxing/unboxing every time you add or get an item from collection.

   ```
   List<mp3> mp3List = new List<mp2>();
   mp3List.Add(speler1);
   mp3List.Add(speler2);
   mp3List.Add(speler3);
   mp3List.Add(speler4);
   mp3List.Add(speler5);
   ```
2. Use indexer access to get item on given index from `List<T>`:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < mp3List.Count; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(@"MP3 Speler {0} Make: {1} Model: {2} MBSize: {3} Price: {4}",
            mp3List[i].ID, mp3List[i].Make, mp3List[i].Model, mp3List[i].MbSize, mp3List[i].Price);
    }
   ```
3. You could also use [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) instead of `for`:

   ```
   foreach (var item in mp3List)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(@"MP3 Speler {0} Make: {1} Model: {2} MBSize: {3} Price: {4}",
            item.ID, item.Make, item.Model, item.MbSize, item.Price);
    }
   ```